# Android recording, uploading and playing a sound

Tags: android, media-player

The application will record sound from the mic, upload this sound to the server and play the sounds from the server(with the android media player). I know it is not a very clear explanation but the main objectives of the application will be these. "android developers" is down so I can not search the topics there. If you know any tutorials or articles about these subjects I would be greatful. (Or any kind of help)

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at [Media Recorder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html) in the developes site. Its pretty simple to use.

Comment: I think developer.android.com is down. I can't reach the website

Comment: I can. If you downloaded the sdk you can look at the documentation offline under the /docs folder